# Как вывести последнюю запись и просуммировать значения?

Tags: sql, mysql

У меня проблема с SQL запросом к MySQL: мне нужно одно поле просуммировать, а для другого вывести последнее значение. Таблица:

```
name        date    interested  made_call
andrew.h    2011-02-04      10        10
andrew.h    2011-02-11      20        10
andrew.h    2011-02-13      2         10
sasha.g     2011-02-11      5         20
sasha.g     2011-02-12      5         1
```

Это что мне нужно в результате:

```
name        date    interested  made_call
andrew.h    2011-02-13      2         30
sasha.g     2011-02-12      5         21
```

Попробовал написать такой запрос

```sql
SELECT a.name,a.date,a.interested,sum(made_call) as made_call
FROM `resultboard` a 
WHERE a.attendence = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from resultboard where name = a.name
       and id > a.id and attendence = 1)
GROUP BY name
```

но в результате не суммировалось ничего, а только выводился последний результат:

```
andrew.h  2011-02-13      2         10
sasha.g    2011-02-12     5         1
```

Comment: o_0. Предлагаю сделать два запроса…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT a.name, t.date, a.interested, t.calls
FROM resultboard a 
JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(date) AS date, SUM(made_call) AS calls FROM resultboard 
     GROUP BY name) AS t
     ON a.name = t.name AND a.date = t.date
```

Сам разобрался. Сделал "невозможное" ))

Comment: Блин.. я подумал, что вы хотите последнее значение не для даты, а для того второго числа :)

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы хотите сделать, сделать нельзя. Вы пытаетесь смешать поиск и аггрегацию (ыгь) в одном запросе. У вас не получится. Делайте два запроса, как предложил kirelagin. Ну или делайте какой-нибудь хитрый JOIN из двух подзапросов...

Comment: Кстати никогда не понимал причин таких SQL изобретений, лично мне проще одним простым запросом данные вытащить и уже в результирующем массиве выполнить все необходимые действия:)

Comment: @winrarhero нееее, так тут другое! Дело в том, что БД оптимизирована для подобных операций, соответственно, работать будет быстрее, чем средствами языка (особенно такого неповоротливого, как пхп). Это раз. Во-вторых. Даже на примере этой задачи — требуется вывести по два числа на каждое имя. А Вы хотите из базы в скрипт передавать ВСЮ ТАБЛИЦУ.

Comment: @winrarhero, ну и запрос в базу у вас положит, если в нем будет, скажем 1млн строк, а клиенты будут запрашивать страницу постоянно. Никогда так не делайте. Лучше запрос будет выполняться чуть-чуть дольше при небольших количествах данных, но зато не будет тупить при больших :)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, видимо полезно мне будет матчасть sql языка поучить как следует)